# Camera is rotating after taking photo in landscape, android

Tags: android

I have an activity which captures images and places that image in an imageview. But the constraint is that I need to place the image only in portrait mode, this fails when i take image in landscape mode. Because image is rotated after capturing image in landscape mode. To avoid this I used

```
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,   
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, 
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
```

I changed in my manifest file like,
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait"

But the above things doesn't solve the problem, anyone help here...

My activity is,

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView img1;
Button but;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    but=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             takephoto();               
        }
    });       

      }

      public void takephoto()
      {     
            Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(new 
        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/img1.jpg"));
        camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);
        this.startActivityForResult(camera, 1);
        } 
     }


      @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {

    Bitmap 
   test=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
   +"/img1.jpg");
    img1.setImageBitmap(test);      
    }            
   }
```

My manifest file is,

```
      <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.a"
     android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

     <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"                       
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Bitmap getImage1(String path) throws IOException
{
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    int srcWidth = options.outWidth;
    int srcHeight = options.outHeight;
    int[] newWH =  new int[2];
    newWH[0] = srcWidth/2;
    newWH[1] = (newWH[0]*srcHeight)/srcWidth;

    int inSampleSize = 1;
    while(srcWidth / 2 >= newWH[0]){
        srcWidth /= 2;
        srcHeight /= 2;
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }

     options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap sampledSrcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
    String s=exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
    System.out.println("Orientation>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+s);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    float rotation = rotationForImage(con, Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
    if (rotation != 0f) {
        matrix.preRotate(rotation);
    }

    Bitmap pqr=Bitmap.createBitmap(
            sampledSrcBitmap, 0, 0, sampledSrcBitmap.getWidth(), sampledSrcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);


    return pqr;
}   


public  float rotationForImage(Context context, Uri uri) {
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        String[] projection = { Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            return c.getInt(0);
        }
    } else if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
            int rotation = (int)exifOrientationToDegrees(
                    exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL));
            return rotation;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }
    return 0f;
}

private static float exifOrientationToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
        return 90;
    } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
        return 180;
    } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        return 270;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

add these functions to your activity an onActivity result

```
 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {

    Bitmap 
   test=getImage1(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/img1.jpg");

    img1.setImageBitmap(test);      
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer may I know from where do I call this getImage1() method

Comment: I have added it in my answer it must be called in the onActivityResult

Comment: add them in your activity and call it directly

Comment: This is working in emulator and now I am going to check this in real device

Comment: This approach taking to much processing time. Any other way to take pic in that orientation which give you image in that particular orientation in which user took image.